# How to limit a foreach on an object in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm working with Laravel and I'm trying to return the whole part of an object except the first thing.
I tried `array_slice()` as shown above but it break the page.

```
{{gettype($formulas)}} --> object

@foreach(array_slice($formulas->toArray(), 1, 5) as $f)
    <label>{{$f->name}}</label>
@endforeach
```

So is there a way to do the same thing but with an object?

Comment: This doesn't look like it should be breaking anything, it looks like the syntax is correct. If you want all _but_ the first element, you can omit the 3rd parameter in your `array_splice` call by the way. Take a look at your `storage/logs/laravel.log` and see if there were any errors reported by your view parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will work i didn't tried it but may be it will work.

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
@foreach ($formulas->toArray() as $f)
    <?php if( !$count == 0){ continue; } ?>
    // Your code here           
    <?php $count++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The thing is I could do like that if I only to limit but I want to avoid first too;

Comment: You know what, just edit your answer with adding a `continue` and I'll accept it

Comment: i have updated my answer please tell me it's working or not ?

Answer (score 1):

This could help you :

```
$limit = 5;
@foreach( $formulas as $index => $f)
    @if( $index >= $limit )
        @break
    @endif
    @if ( ! $index == 0 )
        <label>{{$f->name}}</label>
    @endif
@endforeach
```